# "Value does not fall within the expected range" Error in set_Font(Font font) Method

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, ms-office

I'm trying to save my MSWord-Font in a temp Variable to reapply it after moving the cursor to the beginning of the table (I didn't find a possibility to move it to the end of the table, so if sb has an idea how to do that, I would appreciate any hints):

```
Dim oldFont = oWord.Selection.Font
oTable.Rows(rowIdx).Cells(columnIdx).Range.Characters().Last().Select()
oWord.Selection.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart)
oWord.Selection.Font = oWord.Selection.Font
child.TypeIntoWord(oWord)
```

When running that code I get an Error in the 4th row

> "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Even this code does not work:

```
oWord.Selection.Font = oWord.Selection.Font
```

Anybody an idea how to workaround that problem? :(

Comment: Is this in C#, VB.Net or VBA??

Comment: This code is in VB.NET but does it make a difference?
It will be the same result in each language

Comment: do a google search on the method as well as the error have you tried that..?

Comment: I did try that, but I didn't find an answer that I could apply on my code

Comment: I believe you may need to use `oWord.Selection.Font = oWord.Selection.Font.Duplicate`

Comment: @stuartd I tried the same 1 Second ago - didn't work, same error :(

Comment: Aren't you trying to set the font to itself? What about `oldFont`?

Comment: @stuartd I tryied both :) 
Also
`Dim oldFont = oWord.Selection.Font.Dumplicate`
`oWord.Selection.Font = oldFont`

Same Error

Comment: RE: *does it make a difference* - YES IT DOES. **Especially** between VBA (COM) and VB.NET (managed code) involving COM interoperability.

Comment: I tried the Code in VBA and VB.NET (and C#) and I always get the error in every language :)